# CommunicationException - retrieve corresponding XML response?

Tags: wcf, soap

My web service call sometimes results in CommunicationExceptions due to the fact, that the called service returns an invalid SOAP response. The exception message is:

> Server returned an invalid SOAP Fault.  Please see InnerException for more details.

The inner exception has the following message:

> No characters can appear before the XML declaration. Line 10, position 21.

But how to obtain the response so I can log it and see myself what kind of malformed XML has been returned?

Answer (score 0):

Enable message logging: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064(v=vs.110).aspx

You might be interested in `logMalformedMessages' attribute.
If you don't see anything useful on the client side you can try enabling the same on the server side to see what messages are leaving the server.

Comment: Thanks, I could also write a message interceptor of some kind, however, I'm looking for a solution to retrieve the information at the point of the exception handler.

Comment: I think that by the time you see the exception in your code the message body is already lost, so you will not be able to see it. You should either keep it somehow yourself (via e.g. message inspector you mentioned) or rely on logs (but this require human reading).